# Ruby koans: How does the solution to about_hashes.rb 'test_default_value' make sense?

Tags: ruby

For Ruby koan 40, the command line is telling me the underscore section in this code...

```
def test_default_value
    hash1 = Hash.new
    hash1[:one] = 1

    assert_equal 1, hash1[:one]
    assert_equal nil, hash1[:two]

    hash2 = Hash.new("dos")
    hash2[:one] = 1

    assert_equal 1, hash2[:one]
    assert_equal __, hash2[:two] # <<<< here's the underscore section
end
```

...should be "dos". HOW has Ruby assigned "dos" to the :two key, when no key was specified when hash2 was initialized? I'll be very surprised if this makes sense.

But if you can make it make sense to me, that would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hash2` is initialized with a default value `"dos"`.

```
hash2 = Hash.new("dos")
```

Thus, every time you access a key which has not been explicitly assigned a value, you will get `"dos"` back. Note that every hash has a default value. By default, it is just `nil`.

The default values are not "assigned". When accessing a hash value, Ruby tries to find a value which has explicitly set in the hash first. Only if none was found, it returns the default value.

As a final remark: there is another form to set the default value when creating a hash:

```
my_hash = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = "dos" }
```

Generally, this form is preferred as here, the default value is a new object each time you access a non-existant key. This is important if you want to change the default value in-place (which you would often do in the case of e.g. an Array or another Hash).

For simple stuff, this might not be important though. Just to keep in mind for later :)

Comment: Oh, god. I see. WHY did they seem to imply that Ruby KNEW 'dos' is two?? They should have used :banana as the key!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I completed skipped that it was setting a default value and got pulled into thinking it knew :two should be "dos". Made me think it was more 'Ruby magic'.

Answer (score 2):

The value given to the `new` method is the default value for missing keys.

As per the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html#method-c-new)

> If this hash is subsequently accessed by a key that doesn’t correspond
>   to a hash entry, the value returned depends on the style of new used
>   to create the hash. In the first form, the access returns nil. If obj
>   is specified, this single object will be used for all default values.